How to make topology after adding a notch to the cylinder?
I'm new to Blender and faced the following problem: I want to create a part of the ring with a small notch on the bottom without affecting the original silhouette.
Below you can see the unedited original shape without the notch.

Next, you can see an added notch after applying a Boolean modifier and making a small cleanup. The main current problem is that after adding a subdivision modifier, the edges of notch ruin the original silhouette of curvature.

How can I change my polygons typology to make curves around the notch aligned with the original shape after adding the Subdivision modifier?

Link to file ⬇️


Use the boolean modifier AFTER the subdivision modifier perhaps?

Note, modifiers are not meant to be immediately applied in most situations. Their whole advantage is that they can be left unapplied. I hate it when tutorials use modifiers like operators. It's like ordering special dehydrated food for one's everyday lunch.

@TheLabCat Yes, but the Boolean modifier creates a sharp edge on interaction without the ability to apply a Bevel modifier to it. Or am I wrong?

@MarkusvonBroady That is what I did, but I had to apply it to be able to use the Bevel modifier after.

@AlexKhoroshok looks nice. Why not keep this result? So you want to have the boolean before the subdivision. That is unfortunately impossible. It has to be after because subdivisions usually will not work after booleans due to the ugly topology that booleans create and they will usually always require manual cleanup before you can apply subdivision. But since you want it to be in a non-destructive way using stacked modifiers then that's impossible to solve. You have no choice but to have it after subdivision.

@HarryMcKenzie thx, for the answer!  You gave me another nice idea! I will make a Bevel with a Shader instead of a Modifier and keep everything non-destructive with Boolean as You suggested.
